# Suitable C++ widget for showing static html page

Tags: html, c++, css, qt, zooming

I need to create simple cross platform C++ project for rendering (displaying) html pages (let it be application that displays help materials). This pages can include some images and styles (css inserted in html). So I search for the best approach to have the next functionality in my project:

- Possibility to show and zoom formatted html text;
- Possibility to show and zoom images as well as text;
- CSS support;
- Easy to deploy - widget used in app should be lightweight and shouldn't have a lot of extra dependencies.

I tried to use `QTextEdit`. But unfortunately as the Qt documentation says, `QTextEdit` zoom methods do not change the size of any images.

Also tried to use `QWebView` there (Qt5.4). But after switching to Qt5.6 I noticed that Qt WebKit is deprecated and not supported any more. On other hand replacing Qt WebKit functionality with one from the Qt WebEngine is painful. Furthermore Qt WebEngine module is huge and has a lot of dependencies from parts that I actually not used (e. g. it depends a lot from chromium web engine). So I don't need full web browser in my application.

So what is the best approach (may be some lightweight widget that is free to use) to implement functionality mentioned above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use the `QTextEdit` approach but use [`QGraphicsProxyWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsproxywidget.html) to place it in a [`QGraphicsView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html)/[`QGraphicsScene`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html) context and then use [`QGraphicsView::scale`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#scale) to perform the zooming.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with this library, but I've heard lots of good things about it:

http://www.libnavajo.org/

It looks to be extremely lightweight (< 20 classes) and perhaps something that could work. The documentation is unclear about some of your other specifications, but it's something to try perhaps.